# Take time from one file and another separate file and place the time values from both files into a list c++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to load two files, but I'm having a hard time taking the times that are entered in *file 1* and *file 2*, and place them into a list that has all the times, but if the time has already been entered, it doesn't enter it again.

This is not for homework. I'm simply working on a application project on my own.

--Im building a time list that takes each file in a collection and then loads the times that have been placed into a map to have one list of only times but I'm not sure where to begin. if that makes sense ?

Comment: show the example times in file1 and file2

Comment: What list class are you using?

Comment: Sounds like you can use `std::set` for this I can give you a generic answer but if you had some code that showed the type you are using and how you are using it, it would help.

Comment: "I'm not sure where to begin" is not a question suited to a Q&A format. You should find somebody to mentor you.

Comment: Your rude. Thanks for commenting! NOT!

Answer (score 1):

Simply read the files, insert the times read in an `(un)ordered_map` and, if the entry to be inserted has already been added, skip to the next iteration.

```
#include <unordered_map>

std::unordered_map<std::string, VALUE_TYPE> hash;
while (read line) {

    std::string date(extract_date(line));
    auto it(hash.insert(std::make_pair(date, VALUE_TYPE())));

    // If you want to check whether the last value has been inserted
    if (it.second) {
        // do something with the pair it.first
    }

}
```

**Explanation**:

In a `map`, ordered or not, you're mapping values, so, for each value of type `A`, you'll save some value of type `B`.

In this case, once you have to save some `VALUE_TYPE` value for each date, you can simply take the time string, consider it a key, and, if the key has already been added to the mapping container, it won't be inserted again -- and the `VALUE_TYPE` value that will be kept in the container will be the initial one.

```
std::map<int, int> map;
map.insert(std::make_pair(1, 1));
map.insert(std::make_pair(2, 1));
map.insert(std::make_pair(1, 2));
map.insert(std::make_pair(2, 2));

for (auto it(map.begin()); it != map.end(); ++it) {
    std::cout << it->first << " " << it->second << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
1 1
2 1
```

Comment: could you show me an example of how thats done, im still a beginner with maps. I dont fully understand them, if you dont mind.

Comment: @Cka91405 I've made an edit; hope it clarified the process.

Answer (score 0):

If the time values are sorted in files, it might be better to use `std::list<time>` for the task. Read the values from file1 and file2 in sorted order into different lists and use `list::merge` and `list::unique` in this order. This is because neither `std::set`, nor `std::map` preserve the order of the values they store.

You will need to use [list::push_back](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/push_back/), [list::merge](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/merge/), and [list::unique](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/unique/) and each doc page contains an example.

Comment: Is there any examples of this being done? I've never used list before or set. Thanks

Comment: updated the answer with some links